# How to create an service mesh without using containers on aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, grpc, envoyproxy, aws-app-mesh

I am looking to use gRPC for microservice communication. The services are deployed on AWS ec2 instances. 
As I figured out ELB does not really able to balance the load for Http 2.0 traffic. I looked for alternatives and stumbled upon Service mesh. As AWS supports App mesh using envoy proxy for service discovery and load balancing among micro-services, I thought this would be the correct solution to achieve load-balanced communication. However, we are not using containers, I was wondering how we can deploy a proxy in a sidecar pattern to achieve a service mesh?
Is there any other way apart from service mesh through which I can have a load-balanced grpc communication between services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acive App Mesh one of these AWS Fargate, Amazon EC2, Amazon ECS, Amazon EKS, and Kubernetes.

App Mesh supports **microservice applications** that use service discovery naming for their components. To use App Mesh, you must have an existing application running on **AWS Fargate, Amazon ECS, Amazon EKS, Kubernetes on AWS, or Amazon EC2**.

[app-mesh](https://aws.amazon.com/app-mesh/https://aws.amazon.com/app-mesh/)

[app-mesh-latest-userguide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/app-mesh/latest/userguide/what-is-app-mesh.html)

**Prerequisites**

App Mesh supports microservice applications that use service discovery naming for their components. To use this getting started guide, you must have a microservice application running on Amazon EC2 instances.

You can further check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/app-mesh/latest/userguide/mesh-getting-started-ec2.html)

Comment: I dont have a dynamically changing environment. I just intend to load balance gRPC traffic among a few instances of a micro service in EC2. can i have just one instance of envoy proxy and achieve load balancing?

Answer (score 0):

An AppMesh Workshop was just released at ReInvent.  It gives examples of using AppMesh for all 3 modes of compute (EC2, ECS and EKS/Kubernetes).

The workshop is here: https://www.appmeshworkshop.com/